# XSLT null Check

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an incoming XML payload i wanted to check null for element"ns4:payload" which is a complex type it can content data or null.i have given below XSLT. How we can do the null check for that complex type element. Please let me know.
I tried without namespace prefic my xslt is working. How to do null check for element if that is coming with any namespace prefix. please let me know
Incoming XML:

```
    <ns4:EventInteractionTrackingRequest xmlns:ns2="http://example.com">
       <ns4:baseMessage>
          <uuid>sample</uuid>
          <exchangeType>test</exchangeType>
          <headerVersion>1</headerVersion>
          <username>Test</username>
       </ns4:baseMessage>
       <ns4:payload/>
    </ns4:EventInteractionTrackingRequest>


xsl code:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" xmlns:ns1="http://example.com"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
extension-element-prefixes="dp" exclude-result-prefixes="dp" extension-element-prefix="*"
version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="string-length(//payload)!=0">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:message dp:priority="error">Payload data is not present.</xsl:message>
        <dp:reject>Empty paylod </dp:reject>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "null" is not an XSLT concept.  The element could be empty (i.e. have no content), or it could be omitted entirely.  Show some examples of XML, with and without what you are calling "null".  Generally for any XSLT question you must show input XML and the desired output XML.

Comment: <ns1:TrackingRequest xmlns:ns1="http://example.com">
<ns1:baseMessage>
<uuid>232441</uuid>
<headerversion>1.0</headerversion>
</ns1:baseMessage>
<ns1:payload/>
</ns1:TrackingRequest>

Comment: I need to do null check for complex type element "ns1:payload" which is complex type can contain child element.payload tag can come with any name space prefix . Please let me know how to null check for that complex type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the input you show us declares: `xmlns:ns2="http://example.com"` -  but the prefix used is actually `ns4`. That cannot work.

Assuming that's just a typo, your next problem is that you are ignoring the payload's namespace. Since you have declared that namespace in your stylesheet as `xmlns:ns1="http://example.com"`, you need to change the test:

```
<xsl:when test="string-length(//payload)!=0">
```

to:

```
<xsl:when test="string-length(//ns1:payload)!=0">
```

or just:

```
<xsl:when test="string(//ns1:payload)">
```

or - since you say that payload is complex type - test for:

```
<xsl:when test="//ns1:payload/node()">
```

Comment: Hi Michael, Yes that's typo error. So basically i need to do null check for complex type element "payload" which is having any namespace prefix.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "*any namespace prefix*". The actual prefix is immaterial; what maters is the namespace URI. If you know that the namespace URI is `"http://example.com"`, assign it a prefix (as you have done), and use that prefix when addressing the elements in that namespace (as shown above).

Comment: Hi Michael, sorry for the confusion i mean it can have some like xmlns:ns1="http://example.com or xmlns:ns2="http://example.com URI would be same but prefix may change.so while doing null check for payload element how can we put <xsl:when test="//ns1:payload/node()"> ,because instead of ns1 it can have ns2  or enything else. please let me know if this explanation is clear or not. I got the solution given by Tom .We can use local-name() function to access an element independently of its namespace.Thanks for your help

Comment: @user5458829 It doesn't matter what prefix the XML uses. You define your own prefix in the XSLT.

Comment: Yes, You are correct i tested and it is working fine. It doesn't matter any name space prefix. thanks a lot for your input

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xpath local-name() function to access an element independently of its namespace.

Comment: You *can*, but you should not. Best practice is to assume the namespace is there for a reason.